# Babel not recognizing TypeScript syntax when running test using jest on TypeScript file

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, babeljs

```
"dependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^14.14.13"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.12.7",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.19",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "ts-jest": "^26.4.4",
    "typescript": "^4.1.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest"
  }
```

Above is my current package.json file. I'm trying to run test on single file. Right from the beginning of my function, it points at semicolon then I get bunch of babel parser errors. I npm installed all the related dependencies for unit testing on typescript. Am I missing more dependencies to install or is it more of configuration error?

```
const getTwoSum = (file: string[])
```

```
    at Parser._raise (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/error.js:60:45)
          at Parser.raiseWithData (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/error.js:55:17)
          at Parser.raise (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/error.js:39:17)
          at Parser.unexpected (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/util.js:139:16)
          at Parser.expect (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/util.js:116:28)
          at Parser.parseParenAndDistinguishExpression (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.js:1364:14)
          at Parser.parseExprAtom (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.js:1035:21)
          at Parser.parseExprSubscripts (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.js:565:23)
          at Parser.parseUpdate (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.js:545:21)
          at Parser.parseMaybeUnary (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.js:529:17)
```

Comment: Do you have a Babel config?

Comment: No, I didn't touch Babel config. I don't even see one. Do I need to create one? I thought installing dependencies would get the job done.

Comment: Installing packages doesn't activate them, you'll need to configure Babel for that to happen.

Comment: Did you manage to get it to work?